# Copying only data from model tables to new database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have recently upgraded my django from 1.11 -> 3.0 and my python from 2.7 -> 3.6.  During this process, I lost the abiltiy to use `makemigrations` and squashing without throwing an error about one of the previous migrations (of which i don't know which one is causing it.)  During this process, I provisioned a new database and did a direct copy from the previous version using Heroku's CLI. I have data in the tables I still need and don't want to manually try to reinsert to a fresh database.

To circumvent the issues with migrating, I deleted all of the migration files and did a new `makemigrations` call.  It succeeded.  The issue is now my migration status in my copied database don't match the migration numbers in the migration files, therefore cannot be executed via `migrate`.  So the question is this:

1. Is there a way to provision a blank database, apply the
   migrations, then copy only the data from the model tables into the
   new database; or
2. Change the migration numbers in the copied
       database so they don't interfere with the updated number of
       migrations in the directory?

Comment: If you don't need to apply any migrations (you're sure that the new migrations match your DB) then you can delete all the rows from the migrations table and then run `migrate --fake` to mark those migrations as applied but not actually run them

Comment: I have 1 new model that hasn't been applied and that I was trying to get applied during this process.

Comment: If you remove that model (comment it out) and follow the above steps. You can then create another migration to add the new model and apply that migration

Comment: My dude, you've done it.  Thanks.  I wish this was an answer so I could accept it.